# Implication review!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I am currently studying for my Discrete Structures final exam, and there is a question I am not sure how to answer...
Question is:

> Consider the following implication.
>
> "If i do not debug the code or someone tests the program then the
>   program has problems."
>
> State the following:  1)Inverse 2)Convere 3)Contrapositive

I got the inverse correct, but not the converse and contrapositive. also would someone mind explaining what they mean? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The **converse** of an "if P, then Q" statement is "if Q, then P".

The **contrapositive** of an "if P, then Q" statement is "if not Q, then not P".

Now you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 3):

Let

$p$: "I debug the code."

$q$: "Someone tests the program."

$r$: "The program has problems."

Then your original statement is $(\neg p \vee q) \rightarrow r$.

- The inverse(i.e. put negation both sides): $\neg(\neg p \vee q) \rightarrow \neg r$ , which is equivalent to, by De Morgan's Law, $(p \wedge \neg q) \rightarrow \neg r $

  (This inverse says "If I debug the code and someone does not test the program then the  program has problems.")
- The converse(i.e. reverse the arrow): $r \rightarrow (\neg p \vee q)$
- The contrapositive(i.e. both reverse the arrow and put negation on both sides): $\neg r \rightarrow \neg(\neg p \vee q)$, which is equivalent to $\neg r \rightarrow(p \wedge \neg  q)$. Observe  that this statement is indeed equivalent to saying your original statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a statement of the form "If $p$, then $q$, the converse is the statement "If $q$, then $p$," and the contrapositive is the statement "If not-$q$, then not-$p$."

The contrapositive is always logically equivalent to the original statement, but the converse is not in general.